# How do I install packages for Sublime text?

Tags: package-management, sublime-text

How can I install plugins/packages in Sublime Text 2 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and use that to install further packages. Make sure you select the Sublime Text 2 version of the code you need to paste in.

And meta sidebar: I'm not providing code here because as the website says, it's very volatile.

---

The alternative is manually downloading plugins and sticking them in and around `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`. But I'd seriously look at Package Control.